# How to update cache after GraphQL mutation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

Hello I want to update my local cache after I mutated with network request to my API.
This is my Apollo query:

```js
    const CREATE_POST = gql`
  mutation createPost($title: String!, $body: String!, $userId: Int!) {
    createPost(title: $title, body: $body, userId: $userId) {
      title
      body
      userId
    }
  }
`;



  const [createPost] = useMutation(CREATE_POST);

const variables = { title, body, userId: numbered };
console.log('variables', variables);
createPost({
  variables,
  update(cache) {
    const results = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_POSTS });
    console.log(results);
    // cache.writeQuery({
    //   query: GET_POSTS,
    //   data: {
    //     posts: [...posts, variables],
    //   },
    // });
  },
});
```

I am able to create a Post into the database, however I want to also update my local Apollo cache after I make the mutation request, however when I log results here I don't get anything.

Am I implementing the local cache update after inserting into db correctly?

Also in my typePolicies for inMemoryCache settings I have deep merge

```js
typePolicies: {
  Query: {
    fields: {
      posts: {
        keyArgs: ['limit'],
        merge: (existing, incoming) => {
          console.log('existing', existing);
          console.log('incoming', incoming);
          const result = [...(existing || []), ...incoming];
          return result;
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **refetch();**

Official doc - [refetch](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/refetching)

```
const onSubmit =  () => {
       
        const variables = { title, body, userId: numbered };
        console.log('variables', variables);
        createPost({
        variables,
        update(cache) {
            const results = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_POSTS });
            console.log(results);
            // cache.writeQuery({
            //   query: GET_POSTS,
            //   data: {
            //     posts: [...posts, variables],
            //   },
            // });
        },
        });
        refetch();

  };
```